# Typescript polymorphism with class

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, polymorphism

I try to create a function to create a piece of chess almost like the document.createElement:

```js
class pawn extends piece {

}

class bishop extends piece {

}

class rook extends piece {

}

class king extends piece {

}

class queen extends piece {

}

class knigth extends piece {

}

export interface pieces {
    "pawn": pawn
    "bishop": bishop
    "rook": rook
    "king": king
    "queen": queen
    "knigth": knigth
}

export function createPiece<K extends keyof pieces>(pieceName: K, options?: pieceInit): pieces[K]{
    /// ???
}
```

But I don't know what I need to return in my createPiece function...
I try

```
export function createPiece<K extends keyof pieces>(pieceName: K, options?: pieceInit): pieces[K]{
     return pieces[pieceName]
}
```

But I got the following error : 'pieces' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

My goal is :

```
const piece1:pawn = createPiece("pawn");
const piece2:queen = createPiece("queen");
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `pieces` as an `interface`. You can only access information about interfaces during compile-time and *not* during runtime. That's why the line `return pieces[pieceName]` fails to compile.

You should instead define `pieces` as an object.

```
export const pieces = {
    "pawn": pawn,
    "bishop": bishop,
    "rook": rook,
    "king": king,
    "queen": queen,
    "knigth": knigth
}
```

We can use this object to look up the keys during runtime **and** we can also extract the type information of `pieces` for use during compile-time.

```
export function createPiece<
  K extends keyof typeof pieces
>(pieceName: K): typeof pieces[K] {
  return pieces[pieceName]
}
```

So instead of using `pieces` directly in the generic type, you can use `typeof pieces` to get the type of the `pieces` object.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=2&pln=25&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAOYHcB20CmAPALqpATGsAlqsKtAN4BQlAvtaJDAEaEQAWA9rGljvnMVIVqdSgyjQAThw4BrHtjwFBZKrXrgJswkgDmCvspKqRGxtACOAV1Q4DSgceHqxmmLKSFdmNvf5EnNVEMWA5JTGhgDiQICIDSGABeYWhU6AAieGR0gC44RCQAGko0jJZ2Llzocs5YYtL06Tkqptl6tPTtPSqu3XbU9OtbJCqhnH6Mjy8fHs9vNhcQsIiAMyskYExCaMjJVDBsAAUVAB4AaT93VABPDhXoTGvYVDvHBIA%20AAp41AA5MAAtqg8mcAJR5R7PV4-CAAbTOAF0qKU9pgrJIUDDYT9-kCEbQgA)

Comment: Ok ! I use the interface way because I read the declaration of createElement (from the Document interface) in lib.dom.d.ts and they used interface

Answer (score 1):

You can if you define the interface as a const. Fully typed it would look like so:

```
type PiecesKey = keyof Pieces;
type Piece<T extends PiecesKey> = Pieces[T];

type Pieces = {
    pawn: pawn;
    bishop: bishop;
    rook: rook;
    king: king;
    queen: queen;
    knigth: knigth;
};

const pieces = {
    pawn: pawn,
    bishop: bishop,
    rook: rook,
    king: king,
    queen: queen,
    knigth: knigth,
};

type pieceInit = {};

export function createPiece<K extends PiecesKey>(
    pieceName: K,
    options?: pieceInit,
): Piece<K> {
    return new pieces[pieceName]();
}
```